# Understanding percentile= calculation in describes () of python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, percentile, describe

I am trying to understand the following: 
1)how the percentiles are calculated. 
2) Why did python not return me the values in a sorted order (which was my expectation) as an output
3) My requirement is to know actual value below which x% of population lies. How to do that?

Thanks

Python-2

```
new=pd.DataFrame({'a':range(10),'b':[60510,60053,54968,62269,91107,29812,45503,6460,62521,37128]})
print new.describe(percentiles=[ 0,0.1 ,0.2,0.3,0.4, 0.50, 0.6,0.7,0.8 ,0.90,1 ])
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1)how the percentiles are calculated

90% percentile/quantile means 10% of the data is greater than that value, 90% of the data falls below that value. By default, it's based on a linear interpolation. This is why in your `a` column, values increment by `0.9`instead of original data values of `[0, 1, 2 ...]`. If you want to use nearest values instead of interpolation, you can use the [quantile method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html) instead of describe and change the interpolation parameter.

> 2) Why did python not return me the values in a sorted order (which was my expectation) as an output

Your question is unclear here. It does return values in a sorted order, indexed based on the output of the .describe method output: count, mean, std, min, quantiles from low to high, max. If you only want quantiles and not the other statistics, you can use the quantile method instead.

> 3) My requirement is to know actual value below which x% of population lies. How to do that?

Nothing is wrong with the output. Those quantiles are accurate, although they aren't very meaningful when your data only has 10 observations.

Edit: It wasn't originally clear to me that you were attempting to do stats on a frequency table. I don't know of a direct solution in pandas that don't involve moving your data over to a numpy array. You could use numpy.repeat like to get a raw list of observations to put back into pandas and do descriptive stats on.

```
vals = np.array(new.a)
freqs = np.array(new.b)
observations = np.repeat(vals, freqs)
```